# Does It Matter What Type Of Capacitor I Use?

Tags: capacitor

My intended use for the capacitors will be frequency/tone generators and DIY guitar pedals.
Is there a specific type of capacitor I should use? If so, any recommendations?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are different capacitors and they have different properties which makes some capacitors more suitable for some task than other capacitors.

But your question does not say where in the circuit capacitora will be and what are their functions, so it's impossible to answer what capacitors you should use.

Answer (score -1):

**Yes. Absolutely.**

There are a ton of capacitor types available for widespread use. Even more types are available for special use cases.

(1) MLCC: Your common ceramic chip capacitor. They are made of different materials representing different sub-groups of use-cases.

(2) Tantal: Chip- or leaded-Capacitors made of tantal-dieelectric.

(3) Electrolytic: Your common SMD (but not chip) and leaded-capacitor. Made of different types of dieelectrics and for different uses cases (Low ESR, long lifetime, wide tempratur range and so on...)

(4) Discrete: Made of specialized cables wound in special ways. Used for e.g. old-school S&H capacitors in discrete A/D frontends

(5) .... and the list goes on.

**In general, choosing the correct type of capacitor is a science in it self - or it is not**

Most times - in digital circuits - you go with your standard parts, because they are cheap & available. Nothing special to them.

Some times - like audio - weird effects have a play. Piezo-Effects in MLCCs, dieelctric aging in electrolytics and a ton of other.

**So, it all depends on your application, your specific requirements (Noise-Spectrum, Noise-Level, tempratur range, lifetime, cost, assembly technology .... and so on**

Comment: Tantalum caps are just a special case of electrolytic caps, and for the most part have very similar properties to other electrolytic capacitors. Never heard of what you call "discrete capacitors", especially not in the context of ADCs. Got a source on that? The rest of the answer is really not telling much aside from "use whatever is standard" without telling how you'd find out what is.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Please see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Al6FCp6N_bQ Minute 28:30 - white coil in the upper rigth corner of the PCB. Discrete Capacitor made out of some sort of teflon-cable and used as integration capacitor in this volmeter. I have seen other use-cases as well. https://www.envea.global/de/s/process-de/filterbruchueberwachung/dusty-c/ e.g has some - in my opinion - weird magic based on special purpose "capacitors" going on.

Comment: Ah but the engineer with the excellent German accent isn't using the word "discrete".  Since the value of that is somewhat critical to the quality of analog to digital converter, I do have many questions about that rather random piece of Teflon cable. I could imagine the term "discrete sample and hold capacitor" was used somewhere to describe that the capacitor is separate from the analog to digital converter IC, and has nothing to do with the construction of said capacitor. Anyways I'm totally confused by your second link; it seems wholly unrelated?

Comment: @MarcusMüller Hmmmh i used the word "discrete" to say "build from simple parts not commonly used to build capacitors" - maybe i missused the word "discrete" as in "discrete transistor arrangement". But i guess, one could also make use of pn-junction capacitances in funky ways. The product from the second link measures the current through the capacitor formed between the metall rod, the air around it, and the earthed metal enclosours around it (Think of huge industrial air ducts and so on) to measure particl-contamination. The particls introduce a charge into the system due to relative movement

Comment: (continue) and their mass and some other factors. We worked with this company once and a EE explained it to me over a coffe. I got the basics, but please don't ask details. I also saw an arrangement to generate extremly high current pulses made of copper sheet metal ( like 2x2m, 50 or so stacked with a few cm's in between). They said, they needed the low resistance and inductance of the sheet metal - again, please don't ask details. I did not understand it. Thse types of "capacitors" are, what i use the term "discrete" for.

Comment: Yep, that's a misuse of the word discrete! It means "neither distributed and thus impossible to pinpoint as a single component nor integrated into something else, a proper individual thing". I don't know what stray capacitances meters have to do with all this.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Hmm i see. I will edit my answer. Thank you for the clarification. Where did you get the definition from? Id like to learn.

Comment: And if you know you did not understand something, it would be wise to state that in your answers. This isn't a confidence contest! It's totally OK to write about something where one isn't perfectly proficient, but saying something like "I might have understood the following incompletely, but to the best of my understanding..." is fair to the reader, who can't tell a doctorate in that topic from someone speaking very self-securely about something they just made up.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Coul you please provide the link to the definition as i asked before? I would like to make sense of it.

Comment: Of the term [*discrete* in the context of electronic components](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/discrete_component)?

Comment: @MarcusMüller I see. A "discrete capacitor" is not possible as a capacitor is itself a "discrete" component. So a "discrete capacitor" is a "descrete discrete component".